# React functional component not re-rendering on its own state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I found a hook someone made online called useStickyState and have been trying to implement it into my React app.

The issue I've come across is that when I attempt to update the state of the useStickyState hook, it doesn't actually update the local storage or re-render the component in which the state is declared. It only seems to actually update the localstorage when a different state is updated causing the component to re-render.

When I run setHelpText() from a child component, the console registers "get item" and "set item" as well as "render app container".

However, if I run setMasterText() from a child the AppContainer doesn't re-render at all.

The only difference I can think of is that setHelpText receives a string e.g. setHelpText("Blah blah blah").

Whereas setMasterText receives an updated array of objects, of which only an existing property of an array item is altered (not the number of array items).

AppContainer.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useStickyState } from "../../hooks/useStickyState";
import "./AppContainer.scss";

//COMPONENTS
import HelpText from "../HelpText/HelpText";
import EditArea from "../EditArea/EditArea";

//DATA
import { HelpTextData } from "../../data/HelpTextData";

const AppContainer = () => {
  const [masterText, setMasterText] = useStickyState([], "mastertext");
  const [helpText, setHelpText] = useState(HelpTextData.welcome);

  console.log("render app container");

  return (
    <div id="app-container">
      <HelpText text={helpText} />
      <EditArea
        masterText={masterText}
        setMasterText={setMasterText}
        setHelpText={setHelpText}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AppContainer;
```

Example of changing helpText state from a child of AppContainer:

```
// Previous state
helpText = "abc";

// Setting new state
setHelpText("cde");

// Re-render triggered
```

Example of changing masterText state from a child of AppContainer:

```
// Previous state
masterText = [
  {
    words: [
             {text: "hello", selected: true},
             {text: "there", selected: false}
           ]
  },
  {
    words: [
             {text: "Hi", selected: false},
             {text: "there", selected: false}
           ]
  },
]

// Setting new state
let newMasterText = masterText;
newMasterText[0].words[0].text = "Abc";

setMasterText(newMasterText);

// No re-render triggered
```

useStickyState.js

```
import React from "react";

export function useStickyState(defaultValue, key) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(() => {
    const stickyValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log("get item");
    return stickyValue !== null ? JSON.parse(stickyValue) : defaultValue;
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("set item");
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);
  return [value, setValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've figured it out!

For anyone that's having a similar issue:

I've ditched using the custom hook. Instead I am passing down a handle function, instead of the setMasterText function directly. This means I can guarantee saving to local storage whenever the state needs to be updated.

Please see below:

```
const handleMasterTextUpdate = (newMasterText) => {
    localStorage.setItem("mastertext", JSON.stringify(newMasterText));
    setMasterText(newMasterText);
  };
```